# Filter items based on average rating in Laravel

Tags: laravel, filter, relationship

I am trying to get **all items with an average rating** that is **greater than or equal to** the input value.

Here is my attempt:

```php
$filters['ratings'] = array_filter($filters['ratings']);
if ($filters['ratings']) {
    $this->model = $this->model
        ->leftJoin('ratings', 'ratings.item_id', '=', 'items.id')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($filters) {
            return $query
                ->whereIn('ratings.star', $filters['reviews']);
        });
}
```

But with the above code, I get all items that have a rating of the input value and not as an average rating greater than or equal to the input value. Which is wrong.

Here's is also another try:

```php
$filters['ratings'] = array_filter($filters['ratings']);
if ($filters['ratings']) {
    $this->model = $this->model
        ->leftJoin('ratings', 'ratings.item_id', '=', 'items.id')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($filters) {
            return $query
                ->select('ratings.item_id')
                ->selectRaw('AVG(ratings.star) AS rating_avg')
                ->groupBy('ratings.item_id')
                ->havingRaw('AVG(ratings.star) >= ?', $filters['ratings']);
        });
}
```

But the above returns all items with no filter. I have read a bunch of posts related to this issue but can't really figure it out. No thanks to my beginners knowledge of relationships. Can anyone show me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Does your model have a relationship with `Rating` ? If so, you could just use `withAvg` to get your average.

```php
# Your model (Item ?)
public function ratings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Rating::class, 'item_id', 'id');
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions

```php
$this->model
    ->withAvg('ratings', 'star')
    ->where('ratings_avg_star', '>=', $filters['ratings']);
```

```php
$this->model
    ->withAvg('ratings as your_alias_here', 'star')
    ->where('your_alias_here', '>=', $filters['ratings']);
```

Comment: I have a relationship like: ``` $withCount = []; $withCount = array_merge($withCount, ['ratings', 'ratings as ratings_avg' => function ($query) {$query->select(DB::raw('avg(star)')); }, ]); ``` within my controller. How can I use the code you've shared based on this? Precisely, my code is going in ItemRepository.php

Comment: You need to define a relationship between the model and the Rating model.

Comment: Aww. Thanks so much for your help. But I do not understand why you use ```Rating::class``` I am simply trying to perform a filter on the objects that are already on my screen. There are also other filters working together. My first code attempt above works fine but not with the expected result. And ```ratings``` is a table on my database, which has columns like ```id```, ```item_id``` , ```star```  and so on... My only challenge is getting to filter based on  average ```star``` reviews per ```item_id```.  Any advice?

Comment: You should have a model for `ratings`, probably in `app/Models/Rating.php`. `Rating::class` resolves to the namespace of that model.

Comment: Yes my model has that... like this ```return $this->hasMany(Rating::class, 'item_id')->where('status', BaseStatusEnum::PUBLISHED);```  I really took the time to explore better but I keep getting ```Unknown column 'ratings_avg_star'``` Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know. It just seems like something that could easily be fixed by not using repository pattern. Since I'm not familiar with your particular implementation, there is no more I can say. Good luck.